# Two Git Repos, One Docker Image

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, amazon-ecs

I am still relatively new to docker.  I have two git repos.  One is a Next.js application and the other a nodejs app.  I need to create a docker container but when building, I need to build the next.js code and move the build folder to the node app before creating an image.  Not sure if this is possible.

I am not sure if this is the best route to take either.  The end goal is to push the docker containers to AWS ECS.

Background, the next.js is a server rendered react framework.  So in QA and PROD the node app serves the content.

Answer (score 1):

By issuing `RUN` directives, executed commands are committed in new layers on top of the current image. The concept behind Docker is to keep your convergence steps under source control as so containers can be created from any point in time in an image's history. In this scenario, using a set of `RUN` instructions will commit each step as an individual layer.

```
WORKDIR /project
RUN git clone https://github.com/foo/next-js.git
RUN git clone https://github.com/baz/nodejs.git

WORKDIR /project/next-js
RUN npm run build
RUN cp ./build ../nodejs/
```

You could instead incorperate the above into a bash script and bypass Docker's layering mechanism.

```
COPY ./setup.sh /
RUN chmod u+x /setup.sh
RUN /setup.sh
```

However, doing so would defeat the purpose of using Docker to begin with, unless for some reason you need to ensure your container receives a set of instructions in the form of one layer.